# How to swap last 2 elements in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, swap

I need to swap last 2 elements of a list in Haskell

Here is what I've got so far and it doesn't compile.

```
swapLastTwo :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swapLastTwo list = case list of
    xs:x:y -> Just (xs:y:x)
    _ -> Nothing
```

However this one compiles:

```
swapFirstTwo :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swapFirstTwo list = case list of
    x:y:xs -> Just (y:x:xs)
    _      -> Nothing
```

What is the difference? I guess there is a problem with these x y xs etc. I am not quite certain with them.

Compiler gives this error

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[a]]’ with actual type ‘a’
       ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
         the type signature for:
           swapLastTwo :: forall a. [a] -> Maybe [a]
         at BuiltInList.hs:69:16
     • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘x’
       In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘y : x’
       In the first argument of ‘Just’, namely ‘(xs : y : x)’
     • Relevant bindings include
         y :: [a] (bound at BuiltInList.hs:71:10)
         x :: a (bound at BuiltInList.hs:71:8)
         xs :: a (bound at BuiltInList.hs:71:5)
         list :: [a] (bound at BuiltInList.hs:70:13)
         swapLastTwo :: [a] -> Maybe [a] (bound at BuiltInList.hs:70:1) Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

First, note that there's no reason to use `case` for this kind of pattern-matching – just match right in the function arguments:

```
swapFirstTwo :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swapFirstTwo (x:y:xs) = Just (y:x:xs)
swapFirstTwo _ = Nothing
```

Now... Haskell lists aren't symmetric. At all. Anything you do with pattern-matching will always focus on the *left* end on the list, that's why your `swapLastTwo` doesn't work. You can only get at the *right* end by disassembling the whole list (if at all, namely, this only works for *finite* lists). This can be done through *recursion*. First write out the base cases:

```
swapLastTwo [] = Nothing
swapLastTwo [_] = Nothing
swapLastTwo [x,y] = Just [y,x]
```

For any list *longer* than that, you need to first pop off elements and then later put them back. Hence the recursive clause

```
swapLastTwo (x:xs) = (x:) <$> swapLastTwo xs
```

In case you're wondering what [`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-) is: in this case, it simply prepends `x` to whatever `Just` result the recursive call may yield.

An alternative, kind of brute-force solution would be

```
swapLastTwo = fmap reverse . swapFirstTwo . reverse
```

<del>This actually has much worse runtime characteristics in this example, but</del><sup>See Luke's comment</sup> generally, such “compose simple functions instead of doing manual recursion” solutions are often much more effective.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works now. Didn't expect it to be so confusing.

Comment: @leftroundabout, "This actually has much worse runtime characteristics": seems like they are both O(n) and spine-strict to me.  If you got rid of the `Maybe`, on the other hand, then it could be made lazy/productive.  (It can be done with the `Maybe` too, but it's a bit more subtle and the naive implementation doesn't cut it)

Comment: @luqui true, I didn't think of the `Maybe` strictness.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the productive version I mentioned for fun.

```
swapLastTwo :: [a] -> [a]
swapLastTwo [] = []
swapLastTwo [x] = [x]
swapLastTwo [x,y] = [y,x]
swapLastTwo (x:xs) = x : swapLastTwo xs
```

It's lazy:

```
ghci> swapLastTwo [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,5,4]
>>> swapLastTwo (1:2:3:4:5:undefined)
[1,2,3*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

And you can also do it with `Maybe` (which is why I wrote this answer, because I enjoy the `asJust` pattern, and the way it can make strict things productive when properly placed — essentially we are codifying some extra structural information that is not clear from the types alone).

```
swapLastTwo' :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swapLastTwo' [] = Nothing
swapLastTwo' [x] = Nothing
swapLastTwo' [x,y] = Just [y,x]
swapLastTwo' (x:xs) = (x:) <$> asJust (swapLastTwo' xs)
    where
    assertJust ~(Just x) = Just x
```

Which is also lazy

```
ghci> swapLastTwo' (1:2:3:4:5:undefined)
Just [1,2,3*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> swapLastTwo [1]
Nothing
```

In a lazy dependent-typed world, would `swapLastTwo'` (with an appropriately accurate type) be lazy without any extra effort, the way `swapLastTwo` is here?

Answer (score 1):

When using the cons operator `:`, the last item on the right of the colon is a list, while everything to the left is a single item in the list. That is why `swapFirstTwo` compiles successfully: the `x` and `y` from `x:y:xs` are individual items, while `xs` is a list.

You can confine a pattern match to a two element List by either of these methods:

```
x:y:[] -> ...
-- or
[x,y] -> ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I have this. []:x:y -> Just ([]:y:x) Probably I still don't understand something...

Comment: The empty array brackets `[]` go on the _right_, like in the example I've shown.

Comment: If I put it that way it returns "Nothing" <code>x:y:[] -> Just (y:x:[])</code>

Comment: You are missing at least one more case. Hint, what should happen with the pattern `x:y:z:zs`?

Comment: Also, you are returning a `Maybe [a]` value which will complicate your case handling. I recommend - for incremental learning purposes - preserving the input list for the `_` case (instead of returning `Nothing`), such that your function signature is `swapLastTwo :: [a] -> [a]`

Comment: you are saying about x y z zs, but it handles only first 3 values and the rest of the list. Why should I care about it if I only need last 2 values? Thank you

Comment: With pattern matching, you need to "deconstruct" the list from the head recursively in order to locate the last two elements. If you only handle `[x,y]` and `_`, then you will always return `Nothing` except when the list is exactly 2 items long. Might I recommend reviewing some [instructions on pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)?

Answer (score 0):

I can not make sure if this more efficient than @leftaroundabout solution but just for a variety you may use lists as an applicative functor such as;

```
swapLastTwo :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swapLastTwo []  = Nothing
swapLastTwo [_] = Nothing
swapLastTwo xs  = Just (concat $ [reverse . drop 2 . reverse, take 2 . reverse] <*> [xs])

*Main> swapLastTwo []
Nothing
*Main> swapLastTwo [1]
Nothing
*Main> swapLastTwo [1,2,3,4,5]
Just [1,2,3,5,4]
```